# F# Computation Expressions: How to use `for` to return a `seq`?

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I'm writing a computation expression that is essentially implementing a **State monad** and I'm trying to use `for` expression.

I can use the boilerplate function `forLoop` or even `MBuilder.For()`, and they all return a nice `M<seq<'U>, _>` which can be processed by further `let!` expression. But when I'm trying to do the same with `for` expression, it fails to compile telling me that the expression inside `for` must return `unit`.

I'm sorry for a large code block that I can't make smaller.

```fsharp
type M<'T, 'E> = 'T * 'E                 // Monadic type is a simple tuple
type MFunc<'T, 'U, 'E> = 'T -> M<'U, 'E> // A function producing monadic value

// typical boilerplate functions
let bind (x: M<'T, 'E>) (f: MFunc<'T, 'U, 'E>) : M<'U, 'E> =
    let a, s = x
    let b, s1 = f a
    b, s1 + s
let combine (e1: M<'T, 'E>) (e2: M<'U, 'E>) : M<'U, 'E> = bind e1 (fun _ -> e2)
let delay f = (fun () -> f())()

// These two are explained below
let combineList (e1: M<'T, 'E>) (e2: M<'T seq, 'E>) : M<'T seq, 'E> =
    bind
        e1
        (fun x1 ->
            let e2body, e2state = e2
            seq{yield! e2body; yield x1}, e2state
        )
let forLoop (xs: seq<'T>) (f: MFunc<'T, 'U, 'E>) : M<seq<'U>, 'E> =
    Seq.fold
        (fun s x -> combineList (f x) s)
        (Seq.empty<'U>, 0)
        xs

// Builder class
type MBuilder() =
    member this.Bind (x: M<'T, 'E>, f: MFunc<'T, 'U, 'E>) : M<'U, 'E> = bind x f
    member this.Return(a) = a, 0
    member this.Combine(e1,e2) = combine e1 e2
    member this.Delay(f) = delay f
    member this.Zero() = (), 0
    member this.For (xs: seq<'T>, f: MFunc<'T, 'U, 'E> ) : M<seq<'U>, 'E> = forLoop xs f
let stateful = new MBuilder()

let mTest = stateful {
    // below is the typical use, just for example
    let! var1 = "q", 3
    let! var2 = true, 4
    // so far so good, the monad returns ("test", 7)
    return "test"
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to use the loops. The following three calls work as expected, incrementing the state as many times as there are elements in `myList`. They also return a beautiful `string seq`, obviously except the last call:

```fsharp
    let myList = ["one"; "two"; "three"] // define test data

    let! var3 = stateful.For(myList, (fun x -> x, 1))
    let! var4 = forLoop myList (fun x -> x, 1)

    // No return value, as expected
    for str in myList do
        let! _ = str, 1
        return ""
```

But the following does not compile: `error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type M<'a,int> but here has type unit`

```fsharp
    let! var5 =
        for str in myList do
            let! _ = str, 1
            return ""
```

So my question is - **What am I doing wrong**?

I'm also a bit confused with two overloads of `For` described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) and how to make use of both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code that you're trying to write is not syntactically valid computation expression. The syntax does not allow computation expression constructs in the expression `e` in `let! v = e`.

If you want to use nested computation expression, you have to write:

```
let mtest = stateful {
  let! var5 = 
    stateful { for str in myList do 
                 let! _ = str, 1 
                 return "" }
  return "something here" }
```

This should answer your immediate question, but there is a number of things that I find quite confusing about your definitions:

- The type of your `For` is confusing. It should be either `seq<'T> -> ('T -> M<'R>) -> M<'R>` (if your monad can combine multiple results) or `seq<'T> -> ('T -> M<unit>) -> M<unit>` (if your computation returns just a single value)
- You're sometimes using `seq<'T>` inside `M<_>` in the result (in `For`), but sometimes your monad returns only a single value. You should use the same monadic type everywhere.
- The `For` construct can be defined in terms of `Zero` and `Combine`. Unless you're doing something special, that is the best way to go. See the [example in the F# specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html).

If you want a more detailed document, take a look [at this article](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~tp322/drafts/notations.pdf), which describes various options.

Comment: I'm confused by two facts: (1) the boilerplate functions work fine with `let!`; (2) `for` by itself works fine as well. I don't understand why `for` can't be used in conjunction with `let!`. I have even experimented writing the same code with no syntax sugar, and it compiled pretty fine as well.

Comment: @bytebuster I think the type of your `for` is wrong (or, at least, not compatible with the type of your `let!`), so they both work individually (giving different results), but when you try combining them, you get into troubles. Take a look at the example in F# specification or in the article - they describe the expected types. The result of your `For` is `M<seq<'U>, int>` but the result of your `Bind` is just `M<'U, int>`. These two should be the same.

Comment: Here's how MSDN describes `For()`: `seq<'T> * ('T -> M<'U>) -> M<'U>` or `seq<'T> * ('T -> M<'U>) -> seq<M<'U>>`, and I chosen the first one, with `'U: seq<'T>`. They don't say `'U` is `unit`. Maybe, it's an error in MSDN?

Comment: @bytebuster I think your `For` only has `M<seq<'R>>` in the result but the second argument is still a function `'T -> M<'U>`, so it does not match the MSDN signature. The second option on MSDN does not make sense to me - not sure when I'd use that - so I think that should be replaced with the one that uses `unit`. The example in F# specification uses `unit`.

Comment: @TomasPetricek, your link to `this article` at the bottom of your post no longer works?  Would it be possible for you to retrieve a copy of the article and perhaps post it at your blog?  Thanks a lot.